# Why program working differently on every run when using async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

So I have a program which moves files within azure fileshare through SMB. The issue is when I am implementing a program every time it shows different results. I have noticed that some of the files are being deleted from their source location while not copied as well. When I am debugging code step by step then it is working properly. I feel maybe its because my code gets executed before the completion of my async task. Below is the sample of code what i did:

```
public static class SMB
{

     public static async Task MoveFile()
    {
    ....
        await CreateNestedDirectoryIfNotExistsAsync();
    ....
    }
    private static async Task CreateNestedDirectoryIfNotExistsAsync()
    {
    ....
    }

}
```

I am using the above code in my console application project by adding the class in my reference then this is what I am doing in this project to use the methods. :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   SomeFunction(xyz)
}
public static void SomeFunction(XYZ xyz)
{
    UseMethodOfDifferentProject().getAwaiter()
}
 public static async Task UseMethodOfDifferentProject()
{
    await SMB.MoveFile()
}
```

Comment: Change the signature of the `main` method to `async Task Main(string[])`. Then you can correctly `await` the UseMethodOfDifferentProject call.

Comment: I have changed it to ```public static async Task Main(string[] args)``` but the error states that: ```Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point```

Comment: Could you fix the syntax in the code? There are some missing semicolons, and the `.getAwaiter()` is not capitalized correctly. C# is a case sensitive language.

Comment: Actually, this is just a reference to the actual code. I can't add the actual code here. I am using visual studio 2017. Don't worry about syntax it is taking care of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the async Main method from c# 7.1 onward but you have to enable the 7.1 features in VS 2017.

Still, if you want to use the synchronous Main method and keep your code, you simply should modify

```
UseMethodOfDifferentProject().getAwaiter()
```

to

```
UseMethodOfDifferentProject().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

`GetWaiter()` does not return the result of the asynchronous operation, `GetResult()` does that. Basically, you are not waiting for the asynchronous operation to complete and the program exits. I can imagine that this will end up as a complete mess.

**Bonus**: How to enable C# 7.1 features in VS 2017

The minor c# versions are not enabled by default and should be enabled before using them.

[image]

Async Main in C#

1. Right-click on the project name and select Properties from the
   context menu
2. Select the Build tab from left
3. Scroll down and click the Advanced button to open advanced build settings
4. From the Language version drop-down select the C# version you are interested in

Borrowed from [here](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/async-main-csharp/)